# unable to import module that is in the same file

Tags: python

I am having trouble importing the `testRequest.py` module. However, the APIsetting.py module is in the exact same place as `load.py` (this script) and `testRequest.py`.
Weirdly enough APIsetting.py will not import properly without `from windows import APIsetting` either.

As I run the script from a program, it gives very different problems than when run using the command prompt. The command prompt encounters problems in other parts of the code that runs fine in the program, and the program runs as per normal if `import testRequest` does not exist in any form.

How do I go about importing `testRequest.py`?

I have tried `from windows import APIsetting, testRequest`, `import testRequest`, and `from windows import testRequest`.

```
import os
import sys
import functools
from windows import APIsettings
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import uic
import testRequest
from classes.app import get_app
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom
from .windows import testRequest
try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError:  
    import pickle


class load_request(QDialog):


    def __init__(self):

        QDialog.__init__(self)

        get_app().window.actionPlay_trigger(None, force="pause")

        self.list = QListWidget(self)
        self.list.resize(600, 400)
        for i in range(10):
            self.list.addItem('item = %s' %(i+1))
```

I expect `import testRequest` to run smoothly, which would then allow me to access the variables inside and use them for a list. However, `import testRequest` is not allowing the program to run as intended.

After abit of testing I have come to the conclusion that the reason `testRequest` is unable to import is due to the codes in `testRequest`, however I can not tell which part of it actually causing the issue.

```
import os
import sys
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom
import APIsettings

try:
    import cPickle as pickle
except ImportError: 
    import pickle

class test_Request():
    def sent_request():
        request =""" 

            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:website="http://www.website.eu/websiteWSApi">
            <soapenv:Header/>
            <soapenv:Body>
                <website:GetList>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <website:_user>luca</website:_user>
                    <!--Optional:-->
                    <website:_pwd>123</website:_pwd>
                </website:GetList>
            </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>"""

        headers = {"Host": "172.65.54.68","Content-Type": "text/xml","Content-Length": "length"}

        response = requests.post(url="http://172.65.54.68/websiteAPI.asmx?",headers = headers,data = request)
        return response
    def write_response(response):
        with open("testSave.xml", "r+") as f:
            f.write(response.text)

        with open("testSave.xml", "r+") as f:
            content= f.read()
            f.seek(0)
            f.truncate()
            f.write(content.replace('&lt;','<'))

        with open("testSave.xml", "r+") as f:
            content= f.read()
            f.seek(0)
            f.truncate()
            f.write(content.replace('&gt;','>'))

    def read_response():
        with open('testSave.xml', 'r') as f2:
            data= f2.read()
            start_idx = data.index('<Function')
            end_idx = data.index('</Function>')
            data = data[start_idx:end_idx + 11]
            root = ET.fromstring(data)

            #for a in root.getiterator(APIsettings.item):
                #print(a.attrib)
                #print('test1')
            with open('responseDict.pickle', 'wb') as f:

                for a in root.getiterator(APIsettings.item):
                    pickle.dump(a.attrib, f ,protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
                    #print(a.attrib)
                    #print('test2')
            return root
    def get_variables(root):        
        with open('responseDict.pickle', 'rb') as f:
            for b in root.getiterator(APIsettings.item):
                variTest= pickle.load(f)
                print(variTest)
                print('test3')

    def main():
        sent_request()
        response_request= sent_request()
        write_response(response_request)
        read_response()
        root_response= read_response()
        get_variables(root_response)

    main()
```

These are the codes that exist within `testRequest`

Comment: I would be careful calling your script "load.py" this could be a conflict.

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out! just changed it to "Requests.py"

Answer (score 1):

If they reside in the same directory then just use `import .file_name` in your case this would be:

```
import .testRequest
```

normally when you don't add `.` python goes to search for a complete module to navigate to.

Comment: Just tried it, it does not work, the dialog refuses to come up